# Continuous Integration with Surround SCM

Tags: continuous-integration, surroundscm

Are there any continuous integration servers that have an integration with Surround SCM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, CruiseControl.NET does.

Comment: I've used CC.net. It does support it.

Answer (score 2):

Surround SCM integrates with Ant, FinalBuilder, Hudson, Jenkins, NAnt, TeamCity, CruiseControl, CruiseControl.NET, and Parabuild.
http://www.seapine.com/scmintegrations.html

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of (but not tested) **[Parabuild](http://www.viewtier.com/index.htm)** (free only in its "team edition"), which [supports Surround SCM](http://www.viewtier.com/products/parabuild/version_control_support.htm).

[image]